# Is it possible to ignore lisp file during emacs startup?

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs version 27.2. I use the a standard emacs configuration for my work and home use on multiple machines, I have created several small local-lisp files(for specific purpose) for checking mails, blogging and news reading for my personal use.

All these files are stored in one directory which is being called for loading using load-path variable, in work setup I do not want my emacs to load the non-required lisp files which I have created for my blogging and mail use.

Is it possible to add any variable in those .el files like "ignore yes" so they can be ignored during emacs startup and similarly do not load work related lisp files when I am starting emacs for personal use?

I know this can be achieved by using git branches, just wondering if there is a simpler method to handle this within emacs.

Comment: Emacs doesn't load anything unless it's told to.  Setting `load-path` doesn't *load* anything -- it just tells Emacs which directories to look in if/when it *is* asked to load something.  Emacs certainly won't load your personal elisp libraries without you explicitly requesting it.

Comment: Test some variable to let your init file determine whether for your personal use or for work. Based on the variable value, load or don't load (e.g. `require`) specific files.